# Custom flight mode in pixhawk flight controller

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller, fixed-wing, ardupilot, autonomous

I am trying to convert a pixhawk drone into a quadrotor biplane tailsitter. Is there a way to create a transition flight mode where a motor pair will lower its RPM for a while until the drone's axis becomes almost parallel to the ground?